# Android TCP connection to C server : String transferred is noisy

Tags: java, android, c, sockets, tcp

This has been a relatively tedious problem for me, allow me to walk you through it, dear helper.

I am sending through TCP sockets several strings from a C server to a Java Android application. 
My first solution, on the Android side, was the following (simplified for readability):

```
protected void receiveMessage() {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String buffer;
            while ((buffer = br.readLine()) == null) {}     //This is blocking, unless a line is read
        dispatch(buffer);
        catch(...){}
}
```

This was running in a Thread, and was working ok. Only problem is, it doesn't survive stress test at all. When sending several messages in a row, it skips most of it (I think it only processes the first one). Forcing a `sleep(1)` between every sending task is working.

Second solution, with a StringBuilder, allowing me to catch everything in-between the sockets:

```
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder(inputStream.available());
String line;
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      total.append(line).append('\n');
}
```

But:

1. It never breaks out of the while instruction
2. Buffer is noisy, although everything is there

Here's a sample of the logcat with that second solution, first message is fine and can be processed by the dispatcher, then it becomes shady, third one is ok, fourth is bad again, etc

```
05-20 16:26:56.901 10082-10204/com.myapp D/RECEIVER: RECEIVING
05-20 16:26:56.901 10082-10204/com.myapp D/RECEIVER: line={  "action": 20,  "data": [    {      "id": 100,      "addr": 64,      "pin": 0,      "state": true,      "name": "Ecumeur"    },    {      "id": 101,      "addr": 64,      "pin": 1,      "state": false,      "name": "Brasseurs"    }  ]}
05-20 16:26:56.901 10082-10204/com.myapp D/RECEIVER: RECEIVING
05-20 16:26:56.901 10082-10204/com.myapp D/RECEIVER: line=���������������������������� ���������������������������������������������~�_������_��������������������������������X�������x;~�_���� ;~�_����������������x;~�_����'������������b@�����������J�_����@������_������������������P��������+V�_������������������X��������i���O���������������������A������@������������������������������������]
```

How am I supposed to do this, in the good way? 
Thank you very much for your responses!

Comment: You did not post the code for reading `total` from your second example. I assume you read it in a second thread which causes threading problems (your "noise" problem). Place your read Strings in a sychronized collection (e.g. List). Also synchronize the read side.

Comment: Have you seen the client code in this tutorial? http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/07/20/android-tcp-connection-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll skip your first attempt it seems very wrong at first glance.  Your second attempt is closer but... You are doing nothing to tell the (android) client that you have reached the end of the message.

If the (C) server were to close the connection, that would kick android out the loop because it would reach the end of the InputStream and that would cause the buffered reader to return null.  Then it would end the loop and continue processing.

---

**If you want to keep the connection open** then you must send a marker from the server (eg: send the string "EOF" on a line and have android check every line for that marker).

eg:

```
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder(inputStream.available());
String line;
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null && !line.equals("EOF")) {
      total.append(line).append('\n');
}
```

For this to work the server must send the string `"EOF"` on a line to tell android it is the end of the message.

---

I think the data noise is being caused by C sending something that it shouldn't.  It's not clear from your question what the cause for this is.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm not sure it's the best solution but for now I've marked the char string I'm trying to send with a tag at the beginning, and EOF at the end, so I can filtrate and eliminate the noise. The C server must be sending part of memory that I don't want. That's another issue! Working on it